# Android Studio2.3.3 cannot open on Macos High Sierra

Tags: android-studio, macos-high-sierra

After updated to macos high sierra , it just stopped in launching scene when open Android Studio

Answer (score 0):

Try it from the terminal/console and post the output here.

You will need to first check where is android studio installed and navigate to bin folder. You will see studio.sh

run this script in terminal and you can see why it is stuck or post it here so that we can help you

> sh studio.sh